# System.IO.EndOfStreamException

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Friends i have a binary file named Vector.bin, when i try to load it for reading than i got the the error message

> System.IO.EndOfStreamException Additional information: Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.

I am new to C# and I don't understand C# in advanced level. Please suggest the possible solution in this regard. The error is raised while reading   "decoder.LoadModel(filename);"
Some parts of my code is below

```
public WordEMWrapFeaturizer(string filename)
{
    WSDSharp.Decoder decoder = new WSDSharp.Decoder();
    decoder.LoadModel(filename);
    string[] terms = decoder.GetAllTerms();
    vectorSize = decoder.GetVectorSize();
   m_WordEmbedding = new Dictionary<string, Vector>();
    m_UnkEmbedding = new Vector(vectorSize);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your file is in an appropriate format and not damaged?

Comment: @ Diligent i think its format is ok,

Comment: one quick way to test is to load file using System.IO class example *File.ReadAllText(filename);* and if this also fails then definately your file is corrupt/damaged

Comment: @Viru, ok i am trying your mentioned procedure. thanks